# Sort list node is missing in Animation Nodes 2.1.7?

Tags: animation-nodes

I've been trying the expression node with `x.sort(key = lambda o: o.name)`, but it gives no result.
How can I sort objects by name in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

expression `sorted(x, key = lambda o: o.name)` works well.

Comment: The explanation is because the `sort`method modifies the list in place and doesn't return a value, while `sorted` returns a new, sorted, list and doesn't change the input list.